# exclude socket files during diff -r

Tags: linux, diff, sockets, socks, parameters

`diff` has an option `--recursive` (`-r`) to do a comparison between two directories (the files inside them). Is there a way to make `diff` ignore all socket files and only socket files?

I am using `diff --brief -r --no-dereference /var/ /media/mateusz/Database/tmp/duplicity_unpack/var/` to verify part of my backup and I am flooded by entries like `Only in /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock: 10001`. These files are socket files that Duplicity failed to backup - and it is not indicating a failed backup.

I am aware that I may write my own processing of output but it has potential for bugs, requires more time and requires me to maintain list of socket files in the filesystem.

Note that empty folders should not be ignored in the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `diff` itself without code modifications. You will need to use `find` to list the required files, which you can then pass to `diff` without recursion:

```
find /var/ -type f -exec diff {} /media/mateusz/Database/tmp/duplicity_unpack{} \;
```

This finds only normal files, as I see no sense in calling `diff` with any other type, so no sockets, FIFOs, directories, device files, etc.

Comment: I will try it, but I worry that it will die on large amount of files...

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem: `diff` has only two files on each call, and `find` has no known limitations on the number of files, though I guess there must be some ultimate limit to the depth and length of paths. You can list every file in your root file system with `find /`, so `find /var/` should present no difficulty.

Comment: This has one serious trouble - it is blind to empty folders. For some reason find considers socket files as directories (`-type f -o -type d` brings back sockets).

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny - I don't understand your comment at all: `find` does _not_ match sockets on `-type d` (at least, not on Ubuntu), the questioner wants to _exclude_ sockets, and `diff` doesn't handle directories (except implicitly with `-r`). To find sockets, use `-type s`.

Comment: "find does not match sockets on -type d (at least, not on Ubuntu)" as I understand (see for example http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/552975) it leads to listing them

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny - That link to your suggested edit (which I rejected as wrong) makes the same change as you suggested in your previous comment, and it doesn't work, nor does it answer the question.

Comment: I went back to this task and I discovered a problem - this will not find files present only in `media/mateusz/Database/tmp/duplicity_unpack/var/` and not present in `/var/`. It has chance to be useful in this case (case of files present only in backup is not OK, but it is rather rare failure mode), but generally it is not equivalent.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny - You can use the search the other way round: find files in the back-up and compare with what's currently in `/var/`, though this changes the requirements of the original question. The `-exec` command will not work as above unless you `cd` to the back-up directory, but instead you can pipe the file list to a script which will strip the leading directory elements, as in `find /media/mateusz/Database/tmp/duplicity_unpack/var/ -type f|while read f; do diff "$f" "${f#*unpack}; done`.